# Optimizations for Solitaire SPOJ

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal, breadth-first-search

Problem Code: SOLIT
Problem Link: http://www.spoj.com/problems/SOLIT/

I tried solving the SPOJ problem Solitaire. However, I ended up with a TLE (Time Limit Exceeded). My current solution is taking around 2 seconds to execute. I have no idea how to optimize my solution further in order to reduce the time. So, I would be grateful for any help in this regard.

Link to my solution: https://ideone.com/eySI91

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

class Solitaire {

    enum Direction {
        TOP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT;
    };

    static class Piece {
        int row, col;

        public Piece(int row, int col) {
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o)
        {
            if (!(o instanceof Piece))
                return false;
            Piece p = (Piece)o;
            return (row==p.row && col==p.col);
        }
        
        @Override
        public int hashCode()
        {
            return (row*10 + col)%11;
        }
    }

    static class State {
        HashSet<Piece> pieces;

        public State() {
            pieces = new HashSet<>(11);
        }

        public State(State s) {
            pieces = new HashSet<>(11);
            for (Piece p: s.pieces)
                pieces.add(new Piece(p.row, p.col));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof State))
                return false;
            State s = (State) o;
            if (pieces.size()!=s.pieces.size())
                return false;
            for (Piece p: pieces)
            {
                if (!s.pieces.contains(p))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int MOD = 1000000007;
            long code = 0;
            for (Piece p: pieces) {
                code = (code + p.hashCode())%MOD;
            }
            return (int) code;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            String res = "";
            for (Piece p: pieces)
                res = res + " (" + p.row + ", " + p.col + ")";
            return res;
        }
        
        public int getCloseness(State s)
        {
            int medianRow=0, medianCol=0, sMedianRow=0, sMedianCol=0;
            for (Piece p: pieces)
            {
                medianRow+=p.row;
                medianCol+=p.col;
            }
            medianRow/=4;
            medianCol/=4;
            for (Piece p: s.pieces)
            {
                sMedianRow+=p.row;
                sMedianCol+=p.col;
            }
            sMedianRow/=4;
            sMedianCol/=4;
            int closeness = ((sMedianCol-medianCol)*(sMedianCol-medianCol)) + ((sMedianRow-medianRow)*(sMedianRow-medianRow));
            return closeness;
        }
    }

    static State makeMove(State curr, Piece piece, Direction dir, HashSet<State> visited) {
        if (dir == Direction.TOP) {
            if (piece.row==1)
                return null;
            if (curr.pieces.contains(new Piece(piece.row-1, piece.col)))
            {
                if (piece.row==2 || curr.pieces.contains(new Piece(piece.row-2, piece.col)))
                    return null;
                else
                {
                    State newState = new State(curr);
                    newState.pieces.remove(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col));
                    newState.pieces.add(new Piece(piece.row-2, piece.col));
                    if (visited.contains(newState))
                        return null;
                    else
                        return newState;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                State newState = new State(curr);
                newState.pieces.remove(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col));
                newState.pieces.add(new Piece(piece.row-1, piece.col));
                if (visited.contains(newState))
                    return null;
                else
                    return newState;
            }
        }
        
        else if (dir == Direction.RIGHT) {
            if (piece.col==8)
                return null;
            if (curr.pieces.contains(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col+1)))
            {
                if (piece.col==7 || curr.pieces.contains(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col+2)))
                    return null;
                else
                {
                    State newState = new State(curr);
                    newState.pieces.remove(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col));
                    newState.pieces.add(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col+2));
                    if (visited.contains(newState))
                        return null;
                    else
                        return newState;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                State newState = new State(curr);
                newState.pieces.remove(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col));
                newState.pieces.add(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col+1));
                if (visited.contains(newState))
                    return null;
                else
                    return newState;
            }
        }
        
        else if (dir == Direction.DOWN) {
            if (piece.row==8)
                return null;
            if (curr.pieces.contains(new Piece(piece.row+1, piece.col)))
            {
                if (piece.row==7 || curr.pieces.contains(new Piece(piece.row+2, piece.col)))
                    return null;
                else
                {
                    State newState = new State(curr);
                    newState.pieces.remove(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col));
                    newState.pieces.add(new Piece(piece.row+2, piece.col));
                    if (visited.contains(newState))
                        return null;
                    else
                        return newState;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                State newState = new State(curr);
                newState.pieces.remove(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col));
                newState.pieces.add(new Piece(piece.row+1, piece.col));
                if (visited.contains(newState))
                    return null;
                else
                    return newState;
            }
        }
        
        else // dir == Direction.LEFT
        {
            if (piece.col==1)
                return null;
            if (curr.pieces.contains(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col-1)))
            {
                if(piece.col==2 || curr.pieces.contains(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col-2)))
                    return null;
                else
                {
                    State newState = new State(curr);
                    newState.pieces.remove(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col));
                    newState.pieces.add(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col-2));
                    if (visited.contains(newState))
                        return null;
                    else
                        return newState;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                State newState = new State(curr);
                newState.pieces.remove(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col));
                newState.pieces.add(new Piece(piece.row, piece.col-1));
                if (visited.contains(newState))
                    return null;
                else
                    return newState;
            }
        }
    }

    static boolean isReachableInEightMoves(State src, State target) {
        Queue<State> q = new LinkedList<>();
        HashSet<State> visited = new HashSet<>();
        int closeness = src.getCloseness(target);
        
        q.add(src);
        int moves = 0;
        while (!q.isEmpty() && moves <= 8) {
            int levelNodes = q.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < levelNodes; i++) {
                State curr = q.remove();
                if (curr.equals(target))
                    return true;
                if (moves==8)
                    continue;
                visited.add(curr);
                for (Piece p: curr.pieces)
                {
                    State newState = makeMove(curr, p, Direction.TOP, visited);
                    if (newState!=null)
                    {
                        int newCloseness = newState.getCloseness(target);
                        if (closeness>=newCloseness)
                        {
                            closeness=newCloseness;
                            visited.add(newState);
                            q.add(newState);
                        }
                    }
                    newState = makeMove(curr, p, Direction.RIGHT, visited);
                    if (newState!=null)
                    {
                        int newCloseness = newState.getCloseness(target);
                        if (closeness>=newCloseness)
                        {
                            closeness=newCloseness;
                            visited.add(newState);
                            q.add(newState);
                        }
                    }
                    newState = makeMove(curr, p, Direction.DOWN, visited);
                    if (newState!=null)
                    {
                        int newCloseness = newState.getCloseness(target);
                        if (closeness>=newCloseness)
                        {
                            closeness=newCloseness;
                            visited.add(newState);
                            q.add(newState);
                        }
                    }
                    newState = makeMove(curr, p, Direction.LEFT, visited);
                    if (newState!=null)
                    {
                        int newCloseness = newState.getCloseness(target);
                        if (closeness>=newCloseness)
                        {
                            closeness=newCloseness;
                            visited.add(newState);
                            q.add(newState);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            moves++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), "ASCII"));
        CustomScanner sc = new CustomScanner();
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (t-- > 0) {
            State src = new State(), target = new State();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                src.pieces.add(new Piece(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt()));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                target.pieces.add(new Piece(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt()));
            }
            if (isReachableInEightMoves(src, target))
                out.write("YES");
            else
                out.write("NO");
            out.newLine();
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        out.write("Time to execute = " + Double.toString((end-start)/1000d));
        out.flush();
    }

    static class CustomScanner {
        BufferedReader br;
        StringTokenizer st;

        public CustomScanner() {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        }

        private String next() {
            while (st == null || !st.hasMoreElements()) {
                try {
                    st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return st.nextToken();
        }

        public int nextInt() {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }

        public long nextLong() {
            return Long.parseLong(next());
        }

        public double nextDouble() {
            return Double.parseDouble(next());
        }

        public String nextLine() {
            String str = "";
            try {
                str = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes regarding the implementation:-

1. I am just doing a simple bfs traversal where each node is a state of
   the board.
2. I have defined a function called getCloseness() which measures the *closeness* of two different states. It is basically the square of the distance between the centroids of the two states. A centroid of a state is the sum of all row values of each piece divided by 4 and the same for columns.
3. After calculating each state, I am checking if the closeness of this new state is lesser than or equal to the current closeness.
4. If it is not closer, then I will simply discard the new discovered state.
5. If it is closer, then I will update the closeness value and insert this new state into the Queue for future processing.
6. This process terminates when either the queue becomes empty or a state is discovered which is same as the target state.

The above approach takes approximately 1-3 seconds for cases where a minimum of 7 moves are required. I would be grateful if you can tell me how I can further optimize this solution.
The expected time according to the problem is 0.896s.

Comment: Use C or C++. Java is really slow.

Comment: Well, the time-limit for Java programs is doubled. I just want to know if my approach can be further optimized. Are you saying that with the same approach, code written in c/c++ will execute within the given time limits?

Comment: I'm sceptical about step 4. Are you 100% sure that correct transition from initial state A to final state B will always have steps that only decrease closeness? It seems that two different states can have 0 closeness and any move would increase it obviously.

Comment: Also, do not copy the states... Just modify one and keep track of movements. Instead of your closeness I would keep track of number of pieces not in place. In one move you can move only one piece to its place, that way you can do some branch cutting. Instead of hashset, I would just encode entire chessboard as 64 bit int. I'm not sure if it would speed up things, but you could compare states by that encoding, you even could do all operations on such ints.

Comment: @PiotrJaszkowski , I realize my mistake now. Closeness could increase during the transition from initial state to the final state. So, my method will not work. The idea of encoding the entire chessboard in a 64 bit int is also really nice. Could you explain the part about moving one piece to its place in one move?

Comment: So let's consider states A and B. Think about B - A as a state B with deleted pieces that are also in A (on the same positions). The B-A state can have at most 4 pieces (it there's no overlap between A and B), we want to achieve empty B-A. If B-A has 3 pieces and you have 2 moves left then there's no way to reach the goal as per move you can move only one piece into "proper" place. This also means that if you have 4 moves and B-A has 4 pieces they your moves are limited only to the ones decreasing number of pieces in B-A.